# Minimizing speed variability with kCLLocationBestForNavigation when sailing

Tags: ios, core-location, apple-watch

I am working on a GPS Apple Watch app for use when sailing which requires high accuracy for a start line scenario. I suspect the additional gyro/accelerometer inputs are actually hurting, not helping GPS accuracy. For example, `CLLocation.speed` variability seems very high compared to other instruments. (i.e 4.4 knots, 2.2 knots, 6.8 knots, 4.6 knots ... , when other sailing GPS instruments read 4.5 ,4.3 ,4.6 ,4.5, ...)

I understand that having the iPhone nearby will make the watch offload GPS processing to the iPhone. This definitely helps accuracy, but does not seem to help variability. When I am testing off the water (walking or riding a bike), the variability is much lower than sailing. I get similar results running my code on iPhone app and on watch (with iPhone nearby).

```swift
    func startReceivingLocationChanges(locationManager: CLLocationManager) -> Bool {
        // Do not start services that aren't available.
        if !CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            // Location services is not available.
            return false
        }
        // Configure and start the service.
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationBestForNavigation // kCLLocationBestForNavigation seems to have accuracy issues when sailing, try kCLLocationBest???
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone  // In meters.
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        return true 
    }
```

I am considering trying kCLLocationAccuracyBest to turn OFF the Gyro/accel in hopes that this may help.  I am assuming `speed` and `course` are simple calculations based on lat/long changes, but perhaps not? I can do these calculations myself if needed. Also interested in possibly using some 3rd party filtering code to "smooth" the curves. Curious what others have tried. (I suspect this might also be an issue for swimmers, and/or mountain biking tracking scenarios where movement is not "smooth" or easily filtered out.)

Comment: Not a solution, but a question: what is the frequency of speed acquisition ? Does the problem occur only on strong sea or as well on calm sea ?

Comment: I am acquiring as fast as I can get the data (seems to be once per second). Most testing so far in sailboats on "moderate" bay/ocean waters. No lakes. Each second represented above - the speed delta each second is higher than I would expect.

Comment: I am just wondering ? Could the speed you get be relative to the water (hence faster when you go down a wave and slower when you climb a wave) and not relative to sea floor as from other sailing GPS instruments ?

Comment: I am benchmarking against other GPS-based sailing units. Perhaps they "dampen" the results, I am not sure. I was able to run another test using `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` and the results were (quite a bit) better, but still not smooth enough compared with the sailing GPS units (all measuring "speed over ground", not actual water speed). I'll probably end up researching some type of "dampening" options next. Because the use case is 100% outside with open view to satellites, the gyro/accel doesn't seem to help me. I am getting 5/10m accuracy with `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`.

Comment: If you have, you could use a DTS ticket for technical support.

Comment: In case others are interested, I used a **unweighted sliding-average** approach across the last 3 speeds. This, along with using `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`, got me results fairly close to the results I am seeing from my other GPS-based sailing speed instruments. All testing has been done with the phone close enough for the watch to use Phone GPS and not Watch GPS.

Comment: It would be interesting to understand why the 3 values that you average are so different.

Comment: The three values are (quite) different because the underlying iPhone hardware (supplying the geolocation info for the watch when in close proximity) seems to have very jumpy course values until the GPS system first starts returning data within my accuracy threshold..